# How to access map in template string?

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, string-interpolation

I want to use values from `gradle.properties` that should go into a template string.

A naive first:

```
println("${project.properties[somekey]}")
```

doesn't work: `Unresolved reference: somekey`

So, quotes required?

```
println("${project.properties[\"somekey\"]}")
```

is completely broken syntax: `Expecting an expression` for the first .

I couldn't find any example how to do this, yet the official [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#string-templates) says **expressions**.

Question: is it possible to access a map in string template, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and as follows:

```
"${project.properties["someKey"]}"
```

assuming the Map has the following signature: `Map<String, Any?>` (or `Map<Any...`)

Alternatives:

```
"${project.properties.getValue("someKey")}"
"${project.properties.getOrElse("someKey") { "lazy-evaluation-default-value" }}"
"${project.properties.getOrDefault("someKey", "someFixedDefaultValue")}"
```

Basically all the code you put in the `${}` is just plain Kotlin code... no further quoting/escaping required, except for the dollar sign `$` itself, e.g. use `"\$test"` if you do not want it to be substituted with a variable named `test` or `"""${"$"}test"""` if you use a raw string

Note that in this `println` case the following would have sufficed as well (which also goes for all the shown alternatives above. You may omit the outer surrounding quotes and `${}` altogether):

```
println(project.properties["someKey"])
```

See also [Basic types - String templates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#string-templates)